# python mysql error <class '_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError'>

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7

This isn't the most helpful error I've ever seen but from a Google it seems to be a typing error which causes the error but I just cant figure it out. Am I missing the obvious?

```
# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = "INSERT INTO spin_hdd(error_count, raw_read_error, spin_up_time, allo_sec, seek_error, spin_retry, gsense_error, power_on_hours, pending_sector, load_retry, spin_up_time, max_temp, sector_count, short_test_time, long_test_time, model, serial, firmware, ip, running) \
       VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % \
       (error_count, raw_read_error, spin_up_time, allo_sec, seek_error, spin_retry, gsense, power_on, pend_sec, load_retry, spin_up_time, max_temp, sector_count, testShortTime, testLongTime, model_count, serial, firmware, ip, 1)
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cur.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   con.commit()
   # get last inserted id
   id = cur.lastrowid
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   con.rollback()
   e = sys.exc_info()[0]
   print e
```

Comment: If you last column is on type `integer`, you need to remove `'` around `%s`

Comment: Also there are many columns, whose data type can be `int`. I am guessing this from the column names. If it is the case, you will need to remove `'` from all those columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it could be due to many things such as an [error in the SQL or the table not being found](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-programmingerror.html). It's impossible for us to tell if there is an error in the SQL since the string formatting could be inserting some unexpected stuff (like quotation marks or semicolons or other improperly quoted values) into the SQL.

One thing which *might* fix the problem is using the [2-argument form of `cur.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14), which will properly quote the arguments for you. This will correct the quoting error Prerak Sola points out (`1` should not be quoted as `'1'` if the last column is of a numeric type.)

```
sql = """INSERT INTO spin_hdd(
            error_count, raw_read_error, spin_up_time, allo_sec, seek_error, 
            spin_retry, gsense_error, power_on_hours, pending_sector, load_retry, 
            spin_up_time, max_temp, sector_count, short_test_time,
            long_test_time, model, serial, firmware, ip, running) 
         VALUES ({})""".format(', '.join(['%s']*20))

args = (error_count, raw_read_error, spin_up_time, allo_sec, seek_error,
        spin_retry, gsense, power_on, pend_sec, load_retry, spin_up_time,
        max_temp, sector_count, testShortTime, testLongTime, model_count,
        serial, firmware, ip, 1)
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cur.execute(sql, args)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   con.commit()
   # get last inserted id
   id = cur.lastrowid
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   con.rollback()
   e = sys.exc_info()[0]
   print e
```

By the way, you should *always* use the 2-argument form of `cur.execute` instead of manually quoting the arguments yourself as this helps prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).